# How to customize Outlook OnSend error message

Tags: outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

I looked around the documentation but could not find an answer. I know you can add up to 5 error messages but is it possible to edit the default message that says:

T**he addin** "*AddInName*" **is blocking this email from being sent?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.